# Keycloak login page with Laravel

Tags: laravel, keycloak

Good Day,

It's possible to use change the login of laravel page into keycloak page? And after login successful, it will redirect back to laravel home page with auth details from keycloak?

It's there any method to implement keycloak login to laravel? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible, keycloak would be the identity provider, and laravel would be a oidc/oauth2 client, after a succusful login, you should be redirected to laravel logegd in.

This might help https://github.com/Vizir/laravel-keycloak-web-guard

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Keycloak authentication in Laravel. this can be done easily using Laravel Socialite.
What you will need is:

1. Configure a client and enable oAuth 2.0 in the Keycloak server.
2. Install the Keycloak socialite provider, follow the steps in the
   documentation link below.

https://socialiteproviders.com/Keycloak/#installation-basic-usage

It works normally like any Social Login.